# Window surface RT hover

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, windows-rt

I am testing website on Dell XPS device, which supports both touch and mouse(laptop/tablet). I have some menus that have submenus and have hover, active and selected css where I change from display:none to disblay:block on the submenus(if no submenu then user is redirected to the page that is represented by menu option).
Everything works just great on all browsers except IE(on these specific devices - touch/mouse).

Maybe there is a solution for this? To display submenus on touch if there is submenu under the selection. Those menu options that have submenus have class "multi-selection" and menu under it has classes "list" and "lvl-2".

CSS looks like this:

```
.multi-level{ 
    &:hover, &:active, &.selected{          
        .list.lvl-2{
            //dropdown display trigger
            display: block;
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone has any ideas how to solve this for IE on such devices that suport mouse and touch interactions(with mouse it works just fine)?

Comment: Well, first of all you can't actually hover on a touch screen device.

Comment: Yea, I know that, but other touch browsers interprete these hover lines as onclick events and display submenus as if it was hovered.
Solution that I have now on my mind is preventDefault when touch and IE == true and change CSS value through jquery target option.

But this seams like workaround and not a solution and I really don't want to believe that with these devices being in the market for so long there is no proper solutions that can be done through CSS.

Comment: which 'version' of IE were you using? This plays a *huge* part to IE's css capabilities.

Comment: Tried from 8 to 11.0.9 - I am looking for solution to work from IE8 and up, because asking user to update or use another browser is not an option in my case.

Comment: IE8 supports virtually *no* css, hence why developers hate it so much. Try looking into css3pie, it's about trying to create backwards compatibility.